# Handling CTRL+C event in Node.js on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, signals

I am working on a node project where I want to write some memory to a file when exiting.  I figured it was as simple as:

```
process.on('exit', function () {
 //handle your on exit code
 console.log("Exiting, have a nice day");
});
```

However, this code does not execute (on Windows) when CTRL+C is received.  Given this is the defacto way to exit Node, this seems a bit of a problem.

At this point I tried to handle the signal ( `on.('SIGINT',...)` ) instead, which results in the error:

```
node.js:218 
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick 
              ^  Error: No such module 
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (node.js:403:27) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mike\workspace\NodeDev\src\server.js:5:9) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26) 
    at Object..js (module.js:452:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32) 
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12) 
    at Array.0 (module.js:472:10) 
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:209:41)
```

Off to a quick Google and [it appears](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1553) Node simply doesn't handle signals on Windows and CTRL+C does not in fact trigger the "exit" event.  The above error should not exit on a *Nix system.

However, switching off the Windows platform is not a valid option for me, so I need a workaround.  Is there a way to handle On Exit events in Node that are caused by the user pressing CTRL+C to terminate the script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used this piece of code for listening for keys. It seems to work for `CTRL + C` as well on Windows.

But then again it only works for `CTRL + C` as a key combination, not anything else. Of course, you could both bind a function to `process.on("exit"`, and call it inside the `if` block below.

```
var tty = require("tty");

process.openStdin().on("keypress", function(chunk, key) {
  if(key && key.name === "c" && key.ctrl) {
    console.log("bye bye");
    process.exit();
  }
});

tty.setRawMode(true);
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Feels a bit ... dirty, but then, work around's often do!  Thanks.